# My generate files from lb4 openapi cli command doesn't find models folder

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

My OpenAPI api json files are in ./reference and refer to models in the ./reference/models folder - so when I attempt to generate controllers/models from the API files, it says it can't find the ./models (not ./reference/models) folder.  Is there a way to set the working directory when running the lb4 cli command? ... or do I have to restructure my files in the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

This looks like a bug in our code generator. Can you please create a small app reproducing the problem and open a GitHub issue per our [Bug reporting guide](https://loopback.io/doc/en/contrib/Reporting-issues.html#bug-report)?